# how to get maven release:prepare to put tagged release in tags folder?

Tags: svn, maven, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

My project's repo is set up the standard structure - branches / tags / trunk. My project's source is stored in /trunk.

My scm configuration in my pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<scm>
  <url>https://repourl/trunk/scs-global-parent</url>
  <connection>scm:svn:https://repourl/trunk/scs-global-parent</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://repourl/trunk/scs-global-parent</developerConnection>
  <tag>head</tag>
</scm>
```

When maven release:prepare tags a release, is it going to be put in my trunk? Does it "know" about the tags folder? Do I need to adjust my scm configuration? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [user guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html):

> The release:prepare goal will:
>
> 1. Verify that there are no uncommitted changes in the workspace.
> 2. Prompt the user for the desired tag, release and development version names.
> 3. Modify and commit release information into the pom.xml file.
> 4. Tag the entire project source tree with the new tag name.

Your scm settings are sufficient. If you follow the standard SVN naming conventions (trunk/tags/branches), `mvn release:prepare` will be aware of your tags URL location `https://repourl/tags/` and automatically create a tag under here.

If you use something other than this convention, you can specify the tags URL location by [tagBase configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagBase) in pom.xml:

> **tagBase:**
>
> The tag base directory in SVN, you must define it if you don't use the standard svn layout (trunk/tags/branches). For example, http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags. The URL is an SVN URL and does not include the SCM provider and protocol.

- **Type:** java.lang.String
- **Required:** No
- **Expression:** ${tagBase}